# problem to get value in <sj:select > from my sql in struts 2

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I'm trying to get a value in a select box which is saved in a MySQL database. Here's my JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>
<sj:head/>
<s:form theme="simple"  id="forvie">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:label value="Name"/></td>
        <td>
            <s:url id="mm" action="myact" namespace="/this"/>
            <sj:select id="iddepartmant"
                       name="iddepartmant"
                       list="listname"
                       listKey="iddepartmant"
                       listValue="deptname"
                       href="%{mm}" /></td>

        <td><s:textfield id="iddepartmant" name="iddepartmant"/></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</s:form>
```

I have made 2 Java classes. One is `action`:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import dao.Departmant;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import service.saveservice;
import utils.HibernateUtil;

/**
 *
 * @author User014
 */
public class Dropdown extends ActionSupport {

private List listname;
private String firstname;
public String showit() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    listname = new ArrayList();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        saveservice sasa1 = new saveservice();
        Iterator itr =sasa1.getsome().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Departmant dptt= (Departmant) itr.next();
            if (dptt != null) {
                listname.add(new Cons(
                        dptt.getIddepartmant(),
                        dptt.getDeptname()));
            }
        }

     session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

public List getListname() {
    return listname;
}

public void setListname(List listname) {
    this.listname = listname;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

}
```

The second is `service`. There I define a method:

```
public List getsome() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    List list1 = new ArrayList();
    try {
        Query qry = session.createQuery("from Departmant");
        list1 = qry.list();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return list1;
}
```

I got a value returned in the list but it does not appear in the JSP. Why, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Can you not use s:select? What does sj:select get you?

Comment: i tried s:select but get this:org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'idemployee': The requested list key 'nameList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

Comment: I'd get s:select working first since it should be easier. I don't have the time right now to write an example, could you add another jsp block showing what you tried with the s:select tag.  Using jQuery you can manually achieve any ajax results you might want using s:select or hand rolled html and the s:property tag. It is definitely worth knowing how the basic struts tags work.

Comment: You might want to see your browser console to see what is passed to your page. As nmc said if you have configured your action to return json you need to set the `dataType` attribute of select tag to `json` too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<sj:select>` tag requires JSON result.  See http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag

Comment: i have already done that thing my struts.xml  is:<package name="pac3" extends="json-default" namespace="/this">
        <action name="myact" class="action.Dropdown" method="showit">
            <result name="success" type="json"></result>
          
        </action>
    </package>